# Magento 2 Target Rule constantly invalidating in EE

Tags: magento2, cache, catalog, varnish, targetrule

I am using Magento EE - 2.3.1 version with Varnish and my debug.log file is full with the below log

```
report.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"<PRODUCT_URL>","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"TARGET_RULE_1_46234_1_0_0"}} []
```

Does anyone have any idea how to stop invalidating this cache? Because of this our product pages are out of the cache most of the time. It's only happening on our production. We disabled CRON for temporarily but it still showing the log constantly.

If anyone faced the same issue please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to get an answer about this, I'm also getting the same issue!
running 2.3.5-p2 magento2 enterprise

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/198761)

Comment: @RamaChandranM Hello Rama, sure but I want to ask for more info about this or see if its solved since I have the same problem exactly, how can I contact Pribhav or find out more about this?

Answer (score 0):

This comes from target rules (cross-sells / up-sells / related products) block on your product pages which calls the following method: `\Magento\TargetRule\Model\ResourceModel\Index::getProductIds`

As the rule does not match any product, it keeps "removing" the cache in `\Magento\TargetRule\Model\ResourceModel\Index\Index::saveResultForCustomerSegments`

This does not seem to affect performance and does not invalidate Full Page Cache (tested on Magento 2.4.3).

If your FPC keeps invalidating there must be another reason. You can try to disable all your target rules (https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/product-related-rules.html) and see what happens.